# Recursion - Ship Battle

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write a little ship battle game in **java**.

It is **100% academic**, I made it to practice recursion, so... I want to use it instead of iteration, even if it's simpler and more efficient in <strike>most</strike> some cases.

Let's get down to business. These are the rules:

- *Ships are 1, 2 or 3 cells wide and are placed horizontally only.*
- *Water is represented with 0, non-hit ship cells are 1, hit ship cells are 2 and sunken ships have all it's cells in 3.*

With those rules set, I'm using the following array for testing:

```
int[][] board = new int[][]
{
    {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
};
```

It works pretty good so far, and to make it more user-friendly I would like to add a couple of reports. these are the methods I need for them:

1. *Given the matrix, return the amount of ships in it.*
2. *Same as a), but separating them by state (amount of non-hit ships, hit and sunken ones).*

I will need a hand with those reports, and I would like to get some ideas.

Remember it must be done using recursion, I want to understand this, and the only way to go is practice!

Thanks a lot for your time and patience :).

Comment: So do you have a question for us?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Question 1 is not deterministic. And You haven't demonstrated how you want to do this recursively

Comment: I think that you should read the FAQ of this site. This is not a "please do my work" site but a "give me some ideas about this" site. If you want to practice recursion than I suggest you should visit this webpage: http://codingbat.com/java/Recursion-1

Comment: I'm not asking you to give me the work done, but to lend me a hand thinking about how to do it...
I don't know where to start with part 1, I need a kickstart with it so I can work on it.

Comment: Some problems lend themselves to recusive solutions, some don't. This one doesn't (as far as I can tell).
Also, how can you tell where one ship ends and another begins? Two ships of length 1 placed end-to-end
look pretty much like a single ship of length 2.

Comment: I know it is far easier using iteration, but I want to force recursion. And a ship ends when water starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, unless you specify that ships must be separated by a `0`.  Otherwise, `1,1` could be a ship of length 2, or two ships of length 1.

Given that restraint, both of your reports could/should be done as a single process which turns a map into a list of ships.

I don't terribly feel like writing out the recursive wrappers (I assume you know how to do "iterate" over an array using a recursive function), so I'm skipping that part.

1. loop over rows, because ships cannot span rows, they can be treated independently.
2. for each state-class ship data can be in (no ship, ship, sunk ship), have a function
3. This function checks if the next element

   1. Doesn't exist
   2. Is the same as the current one (can be hardcoded by the different functions)
   3. Is different from the current one (go to the right one).
4. As you traverse the array, you assemble a list of ships.
5. You now have a list of ships, which you can count the length of, or do more complicated reports on

It may or may not be better to use a single function that isn't hard-coded, but that seems a tad more difficult, and with only three options, hardcoding isn't too much code-overhead (since all three do work somewhat differently).

Alternatively, you could use an entirely separate method, where by you iterate across the map counting "rising edges" of ships.  This is a much lighter-weigh solution, but doesn't afford you anywhere near as much flexibility in what you can do with the resulting data.

... By lighter weight, I mean "could be done using regex"

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks pretty simpler than people here make it look like actually.

the way I can see recursion can be used here is thinking of the amount of ships in the whole matrix as the amount of ships in the first row **plus** the amount of ships in the rest of the matrix.

If you can solve this, you have it ready.

**How?**

Think about your base case, what is the condition which will stop the recursive calls?

Solve the way of counting the ships in a row.

When you have that, return the amount of ships in the row plus the ships in the rest of the matrix.

I believe your method's signature is like this...

```
ShipCount(int[][] matrix, int numberOfRows, int numberOfCellsPerRow)
```

Say the counter variable is called "count". You will have something like:

```
//Signature
{
    int count = 0;
    if(/*Base condition*/){
    }else{
        /*Count the ships, work with the "count" variable.*/
    }
    return count + ShipCount(matrix[][], numberOfRows - 1, numberOfCellsPerRow) /*"numberOfRows - 1" takes you to the next row.*/
}
```

Good luck with #2 :)

Comment: That's the easy part.. Now how do you use a recursive method to count the ships in a row?

Comment: Well, I think a question we should ask here is: Do you want to solve  all iterations recursively? or you just want to do it with a recursive method with iterative bits? (what I thought)